# Distinct results based on another row's values

Tags: mysql

In this example, is there a way to find only those distinct ID's which are connected to banana and orange? So in this case, the result would be ID 2 and 3 (but not 4, because it has apple as well).

```
id      fruit

1       apple
1       banana
2       banana
2       orange
3       banana
3       orange
4       apple
4       banana
4       orange
```

Comment: do you have only this three value of fruit or more ?

Comment: Yes, only these three fruits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement should work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID 
FROM Table1 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID 
                 FROM Table1 
                 WHERE fruit NOT IN ('banana', 'orange'));
```

Comment: This query will result all four IDs in this case. I'd need only those IDs where there is banana AND orange.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT id
   FROM tbl
     WHERE fruit IN ('banana','orange')
   GROUP BY id
   HAVING count(*)=2) t1
WHERE t1.id NOT IN
    (SELECT id
     FROM tbl
     WHERE fruit NOT IN ('banana','orange')
     GROUP BY id)
```

The first derived table t1 will give you 2,3 and 4 as all 3 have 1 each of banana and orange. Now by second subquery you can get rid of 4, as it will return id as it has 1 fruit, which is not banana or orange.